# Am I using Chromes API Correctly to close a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
<button type="button">Close Tab</button> <button onclick="Chrome.Tab.discard()">
```

I just want a stationary HTML Button that onclick closes the open tab.

Comment: Is this inside of a Chrome extension? Is this a regular web page? Need more info in order to help you.

Comment: No. 1) don't use inline js, do it in a seprate js file via addEventListener, see [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591983) 2) don't change the letter case 3) the correct method is [chrome.tabs.remove()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove) as you can see in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the Chrome API for this. Also, you shouldn't use inline JS. However, if you absolutely have to - it should be inside the opening tag.

`<button onclick="closeTab()">test</button>`

And your function would be pretty simple:

```
function closeTab() {
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: Inline js simply won't work in a chrome extension page unless you relax the CSP, which is a bad idea outside of a sandboxed page. See [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/13591983)